# Error when ordering an UNION MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

The following query throws an error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (' at line 15`.

Here's the query:

```
(SELECT 'receivables'       AS entry_type, 
        rp.amount_recieved  AS amount, 
        rp.rp_id            AS payment_document_id, 
        rp.paidwith         AS payment_type, 
        rp.payment_doc_date AS payment_document_date, 
        r.id                AS document_id, 
        c.comp_name         AS company 
 FROM   receivables_payments rp, 
        receivables r, 
        comp_companies c 
 WHERE  rp.r_id = r.id 
        AND r.supplier = c.comp_id 
        AND r.beneficiary_id = '1' 
        AND rp.payment_doc_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-11-09') 
UNION 
(SELECT 'payables'          AS entry_type, 
        pp.amount_recieved  AS amount, 
        pp.pp_id            AS payment_document_id, 
        pp.paidwith         AS payment_type, 
        pp.payment_doc_date AS payment_document_date, 
        p.id                AS document_id, 
        c.comp_name         AS company 
 FROM   payables_payments pp, 
        payables p, 
        comp_companies c 
 WHERE  pp.p_id = p.id 
        AND p.supplier = c.comp_id 
        AND p.beneficiary_id = '1' 
        AND pp.payment_doc_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-11-09') 
ORDER  BY payment_document_date DESC
```

Can please somebody tell me what's wrong with it? Because I fail to see it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ordering it in outer query

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT 'receivables'       AS entry_type, 
        rp.amount_recieved  AS amount, 
        rp.rp_id            AS payment_document_id, 
        rp.paidwith         AS payment_type, 
        rp.payment_doc_date AS payment_document_date, 
        r.id                AS document_id, 
        c.comp_name         AS company 
 FROM   receivables_payments rp, 
        receivables r, 
        comp_companies c 
 WHERE  rp.r_id = r.id 
        AND r.supplier = c.comp_id 
        AND r.beneficiary_id = '1' 
        AND rp.payment_doc_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-11-09') 
UNION 
(SELECT 'payables'          AS entry_type, 
        pp.amount_recieved  AS amount, 
        pp.pp_id            AS payment_document_id, 
        pp.paidwith         AS payment_type, 
        pp.payment_doc_date AS payment_document_date, 
        p.id                AS document_id, 
        c.comp_name         AS company 
 FROM   payables_payments pp, 
        payables p, 
        comp_companies c 
 WHERE  pp.p_id = p.id 
        AND p.supplier = c.comp_id 
        AND p.beneficiary_id = '1' 
        AND pp.payment_doc_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-11-09')) t1
ORDER  BY payment_document_date DESC;
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that already, but the error was `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: Then provide the alias name to derived table. I have edited my answer to include alias name.

Comment: Oh, thats it! It works now, but when I saw this error I tried adding an alias for each select and of course it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: If it works, make it as a best answer which would be helpful for others.

Comment: Will do that after 4 minutes. SO doesn't allow it until then.